# Select Excel File to be loaded into python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a python function that performs some action on an excel sheet when the file is loaded. When I input the file name into the function directly, it works. But I am finding it difficult allowing user to select any excel file to be loaded in to the function.

**Below is the code:**

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk 
import os

# Get file path
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

for sample_data in os.listdir(folder):
    paths = os.path.join(folder,sample_data)

# End getting path

# Begin Process
def process_workbook(filename):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    #cell = sheet['a3']
    #cell = sheet.cell(2, 1)

    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, 7)
        corrected_total = cell.value * 1.2
        corrected_total_cell = sheet.cell(row, 8)
        corrected_total_cell.value = corrected_total

    chartvalues = Reference(sheet, 
                            min_row=2, 
                            max_row=sheet.max_row, 
                            min_col=8, 
                            max_col=8 )
    chart = BarChart()
    chart.add_data(chartvalues)
    sheet.add_chart(chart, sheet.cell(2, 9))

    wb.save(f'up_{filename}.xlsx')

process_workbook(paths)
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Pytuts\Python_Begin\excel_try.py", line 43, in <module>
    process_workbook(path)
  File "d:\Pytuts\Python_Begin\excel_try.py", line 21, in process_workbook
    wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Support\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\Support\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Support\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

Comment: Are you sure you input the right directory, this exception suggest that there are no excel files in this directory, maybe they are `.csv` files? You can check if correct files are being chosen if you print path to them.

Comment: funtion is working for me just fine. You should check if the file that is beeing loaded from directory is really an xlsx file befor loading. I am assuming that there are some other files in that particular dir..

maybe something like 


    " if sample_data.endswith('.xlsx'): "

Comment: So I want the first section of the code to load a window dialog in which the user can select any random excel file from. But I feel that part of the code is only requiring user to select a folder which should contain excel file named "sample_data". I created a file with that name in one of the folders but it still gave the error.
Also, no files are listed when the open dialog pops up. Only folders show.

Comment: Use filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("Excel files", ".xls")))

Comment: Check the file name. It **must** be .xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all files in a given directory:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder = filedialog.askdirectory()


def process_workbook(filename):
    if len(filename) != 0:  # in case cancel was pressed in filedialog
        wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
        sheet = wb['Sheet1']

        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            print(row, 'of', sheet.max_row+1)
            cell = sheet.cell(row, 7)
            corrected_total = cell.value * 1.2
            corrected_total_cell = sheet.cell(row, 8)
            corrected_total_cell.value = corrected_total

        # for me this part causes errors when saving the workbook, the rest is working fine
        #
        # chartvalues = Reference(sheet,
        #                         min_row=2,
        #                         max_row=sheet.max_row,
        #                         min_col=8,
        #                         max_col=8)
        # chart = BarChart()
        # chart.add_data(chartvalues)
        # sheet.add_chart(chart, sheet.cell(2, 9))

        wb.save(os.path.join(folder, f'up_{sample_data}'))  # some minor change here


# will loop through all files in that directory
# ////////////////////////////////////////////
for sample_data in os.listdir(folder):
    if sample_data.endswith('.xlsx'):  # need to check if file is an excel file before loading
        paths = os.path.join(folder, sample_data)
        process_workbook(paths)
```

Or choose a single file:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# rather then looping through all files in a given directory
# choose a file to be processed
# ////////////////////////////////////////////
paths = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("Excel files", "*.xls")))
folder = '/'.join(paths.split('/')[0:-1])  # remove filename from path
sample_data = os.path.basename(paths)  # save filename for later use


def process_workbook(filename):
    if len(filename) != 0:  # in case cancel was pressed in filedialog
        wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
        sheet = wb['Sheet1']

        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            print(row, 'of', sheet.max_row + 1)
            cell = sheet.cell(row, 7)
            corrected_total = cell.value * 1.2
            corrected_total_cell = sheet.cell(row, 8)
            corrected_total_cell.value = corrected_total

        # for me this part causes errors when saving the workbook, the rest is working fine
        #
        # chartvalues = Reference(sheet,
        #                         min_row=2,
        #                         max_row=sheet.max_row,
        #                         min_col=8,
        #                         max_col=8)
        # chart = BarChart()
        # chart.add_data(chartvalues)
        # sheet.add_chart(chart, sheet.cell(2, 9))

        wb.save(os.path.join(folder, f'up_{sample_data}'))  # some minor change here


process_workbook(paths)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dan_Green 

I tried both codes above and they all had errors.

For the second method, you initially set `paths` to none and supplied it as an argument to the function. I suppose an empty value is passed to the function then. kindly elaborate if I am mistaken

Comment: Hey @Drunk Drunk, I have checked the code and currected all errors that i have found. Indeed there were some of my own making. I apologies! Cheers